# Replacing nth occurrence of string

Tags: vb.net

This should be fairly simple but I'm having one of those days. Can anyone advise me as to how to replace the first and third occurrence of a character within a string? I have looked at replace but that cannot work as the string could be of different lengths. All I want to do is replace the first and third occurrence.

Comment: first and third occurance of a particular character? character as in tab character for example? is this the answer or is this just for first and third character of a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an overload of the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) method which takes a start position as a parameter. Using a loop you'll be able to find the position of the first and third occurences. Then you could use a combination of the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx) and [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) methods to do the replacements.

You could also use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do the replacements. The `StringBuilder` has a [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149403.aspx) method for which you can specify a start index and a number of characters affected.

Answer (score 0):

aspiringCoder,

Perhaps something like this might be useful to you (in line with what Meta-Knight was talking about <+1>)

```
Dim str As String = "this is a test this is a test this is a test"
Dim first As Integer
Dim third As Integer
Dim base As Integer = 0 
Dim i As Integer
While str.length > 0 
    If i = 0 Then
        first = str.IndexOf("test")
    else if i = 2 Then
        third = base + str.IndexOf("test")
    end if
base = base + str.IndexOf("test")
str = str.Remove(0, str.IndexOf("test") + "test".length -1 )
i++
End While
```

It might have a one-off error somewhere...but this should at least get you started.

Comment: what happens if this is a new line character?